# Maximum length for SVN comment

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a limit on maximum length for a comment that we can have for SVN?

I have a script that generates a comment before committing the file at root level, it has all file names in its comment before committing, I am wondering if there is any limit on number of characters on comment for SVN.That is because if I am committing large number of files, then all file names would appear in comment so was wondering how long the comment can be..

Comment: It can't be 255 characters. So it might be 255 * 255 = 65 025 characters, if it has a limit at all.

Comment: Why are you scripting the commit comments? Aren't they supposed to be user entered?

Comment: I'm just curious: Why do you put the filenames in the commit message when SVN knows about all the files you change?

Comment: @Warren: could be writing a script to port data from another version control system, for example.

Comment: @Warren,@initall: we have a tool that needs such kind of support needed by testers/developers. Not every one can commit directly, it goes thru some process before it gets comitted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to differentiate between the `svn ci -m` message you give as a command line argument and the `svn ci -F` or `svn ci --file` version that allows you to specify the commit message in a file.

The command line variant is restricted by the shell you use; my test script stopped with a comment of little more than 131.000 chars. With the -F filename version I could commit dozens of megabytes.

Answer (score 5):

With Subversion (unlike CVS), you don't need to include the filenames in each commit comment, because the filenames changed by a commit are *already* part of that commit information. It's easy to get the list of files changed by a commit without having to store it in the commit comment itself.